# Updating a property of an item in an observableArray and persisting to template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using KnockoutJS...

I have an `observableArray` of movies in my viewModel. The array is updated when a user searches for a movie by title, so a typical json response that would be pushed into the array would look like this...

```
{data : [{
    Id: 12345,
    Title: 'Movie1',
    Year: 2010,
    Character: [{
        Name: 'Character1',
        Person: { Id: 1, Name: 'Person1' }
    },{
        Name: 'Character2',
        Person: { Id: 2, Name: 'Person2' }
    }],
    UserMovies: [{
        Id: 8
        IsWatched: false,
        Rating: 3.5,
        UserId: 'e1e9c075-1ded-4e7d-8d30-d5d1fbd47103'
    }]
}]}
```

The `UserMovies` property of each movie represents information specific to that user, like their personal rating or if they've watched the movie yet, etc.

I give the user the ability to "Add" the movie to their collection in the database. When they add the movie to their collection a json response is sent back that has the updated `UserMovies` property for that movie.

I'm trying to update just that property and then have it persist to the knockout template. Here's my current viewModel...

```
function viewModel() {
    // private properties
    var self = this;

    // public properties
    self.movies = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.searchValue = ko.observable();

    // public operations
    self.search = function () {
        self.isLoading(true);
        $.getJSON(arguments[0].action, { name: this.searchValue() }, function (data) {
            self.movies(data);
        });
    };
    self.add = function (movie) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: arguments[1].currentTarget.attributes[1].value,
            data: JSON.stringify({ movie: movie }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // how to just update UserMovies property and persist to template for the given movie?
            }
        });
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I'm not sure how to update the property but as far as persisting the data to the knockout template I think it's because the `UserMovies` property of each movie isn't itself an observable so if it's updated nothing will automatically change in the template.

I've been reading about the mapping plugin which would make every property an observable. This may fix my persistance problem but I'm still unsure how to update just the `UserMovies` property whether it's in an `observableArray` or via the mapping plugin.

**Update**

I've created a fiddle using the mapping plugin. If I return the whole movie instead of just the `UserMovies` property it will be much easier to update an item in the array. I'm having some issues getting it to work though and I'm struggling to figure out how to create a mapping for 'key' against the `UserMovies` property. http://jsfiddle.net/cmBd9/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with the mapping plugin using mapping options. I set the key for `UserMovies` to be the Id of each `UserMovie` so when `fromJS()` is called it will look to the Id of each `UserMovie` to tell whether to update or add a new `UserMovie`

Here's my updated code...

```
function viewModel() {
    // private properties
    var self = this;
    var mapping = {
        'UserMovies': {
            key: function (data) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id);
            }
        }
    };

    // public properties
    self.movies = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
    self.searchValue = ko.observable();

    // public operations
    self.search = function () {
        self.isLoading(true);
        $.getJSON(arguments[0].action, { name: this.searchValue() }, function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.movies);
        });
    };
    self.add = function (movie) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: arguments[1].currentTarget.attributes[1].value,
            data: ko.toJSON({ movie: movie }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.success) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.movie, mapping, movie);
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you yourself correctly note, the fact that the UserMovies property is not an observable means that even if you update it, nothing will happen in the UI.  Nonetheless, here is how you could update the (non-observable) UserMovies:

```
self.add = function (movie) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: arguments[1].currentTarget.attributes[1].value,
        data: JSON.stringify({ movie: movie }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.movies(), function(m) {
              if (m.Id == movie.Id) {
                m.UserMovies = data;
              }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Definitely check out the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).  My only concern is that the documentation shows how to initially map an object from JSON, and how later to update the entire object from JSON.

However, it doesn't seem to mention anything about mapping an object from JSON and later coming along and updating only **part** of that object from JSON, so I'm not sure if that will work or not.

If you have trouble, you could try having the service call for the add method return the entire movie object so that you are more closely following the model espoused by the mapping plugin.

Comment: I've thought about changing my controller to return the whole movie. I may just have to go down that route. I really like the idea of using the mapping plugin but like you said, I can't find a way to update a property.

Comment: I created a fiddle using the mapping plugin but having issues getting it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/cmBd9/1

Comment: It looks like partial updates are supported, but you have to be careful when doing it with items in an array.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213104/performing-partial-updates-with-knockoutjs-mapping-plugin and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370052/knockout-js-partial-mapping-from-json.  Does that give you what you need?